# Using BluetoothManager and getAdapater()

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm developing android application in Kotlin and I'm trying to get Bluetooth adapter for Bluetooth communication in my app.

I've read this documentation: [Set up Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup)

As shown, i need to write this code to get the adapter:

```
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
  // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
}
```

When i wrote this in Android Studio, I've got this warning:

```
'getDefaultAdapter(): BluetoothAdapter!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
...
Deprecated: this method will continue to work, but developers are 
strongly encouraged to migrate to using BluetoothManager.getAdapter(), since that 
approach enables support for Context.createAttributionContext.
```

I've tried to use the new recommended way like this

```
var bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)(Context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE))
var adapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter()
```

I got this error on the code:

```
Unresolved reference: getSystemService
```

I've tried more several ways to implement it - nothing worked.

I will be happy to get some help with it.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: [`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#getsystemservice). You will need to arrange to have access to a `Context` in this code, so you can call `getSystemService()` on that. `Activity`, `Service`, and `Application` all extend `Context`, so you can call `getSystemService()` on any of those.

Answer (score 7):

If you support older APIs, you should use `ContextCompat.getSystemService(this, BluetoothManager::class.java)` (where `this` is the `Context` to retrieve the  Service from. After that you have access to the `BluetoothAdapter`.

I've created an extension function that I use to get the adapter:

```
fun Context.bluetoothAdapter(): BluetoothAdapter? =
    ContextCompat.getSystemService(this, BluetoothManager::class.java).adapter
```

If you are targeting higher APIs (above 23) you can safely use the Context directly:

```
fun Context.bluetoothAdapter(): BluetoothAdapter? = 
    (this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager).adapter
```